# Not in scope: type constructor or class

Tags: haskell

I've a Haskell code for a game where the complete one can be found [here](https://github.com/keera-studios/gtk-helpers/tree/master/gtk2/examples/peg-solitaire).

The following is BoardMain.hs

```
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Layout.BackgroundContainer
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Board.BoardLink
import GtkPegSolitaire


attemptDragStart :: Board Int Tile Peg -> (Int, Int) ->  IO Bool
attemptDragStart _ _ = return True
```

When I'm running this, I'm getting the following error

```
 BoardMain.hs:39:21: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Board’

BoardMain.hs:39:31: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Tile’

BoardMain.hs:39:36: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Peg’
```

I know that I've made a small mistake. Any help is appreciated.

`GtkPegSolitaire.hs` and `PegSolitaire.hs` can be found [here](https://github.com/keera-studios/gtk-helpers/tree/master/gtk2/examples/peg-solitaire)

Comment: I'm guessing that you've forgotten to export those types from the `GtkPegSolitaire` module. Could you include the source code for `GtkPegSolitaire.hs`?

Comment: I have rolled back your changes because removing the code makes it impossible to identify your concrete issue. Stack Overflow questions should be self-contained. If you want to trim your question, be sure to leave enough behind so that the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43350243/5524175) mentioned above, I've forgotten to import some modules.
So, what all that should be done is add the following 4 lines to BoardMain.hs

```
import PegSolitaire
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Board.TiledBoard
import Data.Maybe
import Control.Monad
```

`GtkPegSolitaire.hs` and `PegSolitaire.hs` are correct.
The [author](https://github.com/ivanperez-keera) of this game has been notified of this issue.
Thanks [duplode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2751851/duplode) for helping us.

Answer (score 3):

The definitions of your types are in `PegSolitaire`, but you do not import it in the main module. There, you have only imported `GtkPegSolitaire` and a handful of library modules. Imports are not transitive, so you need to add `import PegSolitaire` to the main module. (If imports were transitive, it would, for one, be impossible for library writers to keep modules hidden from the public API.)

Comment: @Sumanth This means you are not importing the module which defines `Board` (as far as I can tell, it is [`Graphics.UI.Gtk.Board.TiledBoard`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-helpers-0.0.7/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Board-TiledBoard.html))

Comment: @Sumanth [*gtk-helpers*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-helpers-0.0.7) is a library, so you need to install it (e.g. with *cabal install* before you can use it).

Comment: @Sumanth [1/2] (1) Note that the compiler is now complaining about different things not being in scope. In this case, `when`, `isJust` and `isNothing` are functions from the `Control.Monad` and `Data.Maybe` modules from the standard libraries, which the author of the example has seemingly forgotten to import (or perhaps the other modules used to re-export the functions, and then they ceased to do so in some version of the library but the example wasn't updated -- but I'm only speculating).

Comment: @Sumanth [2/2] (2) In such situations, when you can't find something you think that should exist, [Hoogle](https://www.stackage.org/lts-8.9/hoogle) can be useful. (3) Importing a module brings in scope all definitions in its export list. If there is no export list in the other module, all of its top-level definitions will be brought in. (You can also bring in only some of the definitions by adding an import list).

Comment: The problem has been fixed when I've imported some modules and the functions from `Control.Monad` and `Data.Maybe`. Thanks @duplode